# Regex replace not working when trying to replace a string - JS

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a bunch of common regex patterns which I got from [here](http://geniuscarrier.com/common-regular-expressions-in-javascript/). I try applying them to a string but they do not seem to modify anything. It just returns me the same value. Can you please enlighten me on what I am doing wrong.

```js
const str = 'sadas87676szdhgzshdgszhjg,##%$,.%';

const commonRegexPatterns = {
  DIGITS: /^[0-9]+$/,
  ALPHABETIC: /^[a-zA-Z]+$/,
  ALPHANUMERIC: /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/,
  DATE: /^(0?[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](19|20)?[0-9]{2}$/,
  EMAIL: /^[a-zA-Z0-9._%-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/,
  ZIP: /^[0-9]{5}(?:-[0-9]{4})?$/,
  DIGITSWITHCOMMA: /^[\d,]/,
  DIGITSWITHCOMMAPERCENTAGE: /^[\d,%]/,
}

console.log('DIGITS', str.replace(commonRegexPatterns.DIGITS, ''));
console.log('ALPHABETIC', str.replace(commonRegexPatterns.ALPHABETIC, ''));
console.log('ALPHANUMERIC', str.replace(commonRegexPatterns.ALPHANUMERIC, ''));
console.log('DIGITSWITHCOMMA', str.replace(commonRegexPatterns.DIGITSWITHCOMMA, ''));
console.log('DIGITSWITHCOMMAPERCENTAGE', str.replace(commonRegexPatterns.DIGITSWITHCOMMAPERCENTAGE, ''));
console.log('ZIP', str.replace(commonRegexPatterns.ZIP, ''));
```

Comment: You need to work on returned value of `.replace`

Answer (score 1):

Well, your regex patterns are wrong. Ok, not really "wrong", but they are not what you seem to want. For example, `DIGITS`:

```
^[0-9]+$
```

This pattern has anchors (the `^` is the start of the string, the `$` is the end). It will match an entire string of numbers, but not just any number inside a string. For your purpose, you want it without the anchors, like:

```
[0-9]+
```

The same applies to most of the other patterns in your snippet. Remove the anchors if you are just trying to match part of a string.
Additionally, since you seem to be trying to remove all occurrences of patterns in the string, you probably want to use the [`g` flag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#advanced_searching_with_flags) in your patterns. For example, `ALPHABETIC` (without the anchors):

```
/[a-zA-Z]+/
```

This will match the first group of letters in your string, but not the ones after it. If instead you use

```
/[a-zA-Z]+/g
```

You will be able to replace every match.

Comment: I was thinking about it, but then I noticed in the docs that's only the case if the pattern is a string, which is not the case for OP.

Comment: You're right and I'll update the answer. I probably misunderstood that part of the MDN docs.